# Azure Functions timeout for Consumption plan more than 10 min

Tags: azure-functions

I use Azure Functions with Consumption plan. My host file

{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
    },

}
So it seems that default timeout should be only 5 minutes. But as I see my functions process even more that 10 minutes. How it could be?

Example
Start  18:16:01.723
Executing 'Functions

18:31:06.417
Executed 'Functions

Comment: What trigger you are using?

Comment: @BowmanZhu, queque trigger

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Application Insights to check your function's execution time? For the maximum execution time of Consumption plan-based functions are 10 mins only.